# Using a javascript switch statement to check if Items in an array is equal

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a list of items. The items in the list change dynamically. I have set that when you hover over an element it calls a function: `onmouseover="hover(this)"` and then I have an array of all the items in the list `document.getElementById("list").getElementsByTagName("li")`

How would I code a switch statement that runs through the array and checks which position the list item sits?

Comment: Why would you code a switch statement? You need to loop through it and do a single compare, no?

Comment: even looping is not needed. Those are real objects he works with. All he needs to do is get the parent LI of the `this` element he hovers above. Don't have the energy top write the code, so a comment...